# .sh script error issues

Tags: bash, shell, postgresql

I have a sh script with which I connect to postgres DB and execute a psql command. The script is as shown below:

```
/opt/postgres/9.2/bin/psql pcwh  -U  pcwhuser << EOF 
 \i /opt/emms/emsam/tmp/tmp1438861364196.psql 
EOF
```

When I try to run this sh file I get an error "file not found". If I execute these statements from command line manually it works, but I need them to work this from script as well.

Comment: How are you trying to run this script?

Comment: sh    <filename>.sh from command line

Answer (score 0):

User should be database user. Who has credential to access pgsql database.
Confirm it using `su - <dbuser>`

Then run script cause in your script  `\i /opt/emms/emsam` only can run user who has permission to access DB.

Comment: I have executed them manually as pcwhuser from CLI so it works.its only I need to do this through script. thank you